# Estrutura MVP Android

Tags: android

Estou estudando MVP e fiquei com dúvida  de como eu deveria estruturar meus pacotes no android. Na internet achei esse modelo, mas não sei se é o melhor
[projeto no github](https://github.com/antoniolg/androidmvp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/antonioleiva/mvpexample/app).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há bastante discussão sobre qual seria a forma ideal de implementar o padrão *Model View Presenter* no **Android**. Como não existe uma fórmula "correta", ficará ao teu critério qual caminho escolher. Separar interface da lógica no Android é uma tarefa árdua, mas o padrão MVP torna um pouco mais fácil impedir que nossas atividades acabem se degradando em classes muito acopladas que consistem em centenas ou milhares de linhas. É essencial organizar o código bem em grandes aplicações, caso contrário, torna-se impossível manter e estender-lo.

Veja abaixo alguns artigos que te ajudará você a entender, para que possa analisar melhor de acordo com sua necessidade:

- [Desmistificando o MVC e MVP no Android](https://medium.com/android-dev-br/desmistificando-o-mvc-e-mvp-no-android-abe927d01df7)
- [MVP for Android](http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android)<sup>(en)</sup>
- [Introdução ao MVP no Android](http://konmik.com/post/introduction_to_model_view_presenter_on_android/) <sup>(en)</sup>
- [Model-View-Presenter: Android guidelines](https://medium.com/@cervonefrancesco/model-view-presenter-android-guidelines-94970b430ddf)<sup>(en)</sup>

E esses repositórios com alguns detalhes:

- [android-architecture](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp)
- [android-mvp-architecture](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvp-architecture)

Veja abaixo como basicamente é organizado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De acordo com o [android-mvp-architecture](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvp-architecture) no Github, veja uma aplicação básica como seria sua arquitetura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quanto ao [projeto no GitHub](https://github.com/antoniolg/androidmvp), podes observar que bastante gente favoritou e provavelmente, digo provavelmente, aderiu. Geralmente a pessoa para chegar no ponto de usar este método, deve também ter realizado diversas outras pesquisas e chegou numa conclusão.

Como sugerido pelo *@márcio-oliveira*, o próprio Google fornece um CodeLab com uma breve introdução sobre a Arquitetura MVP: [Model-View-Presenter (MVP) Architecture](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#3).

Comment: Nesse codelabs da Google também tem uma boa introdução ao MVP: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#3

Comment: @MárcioOliveira editei e inseri na resposta. Vlw.